# Python: Running Powershell Command inside Python script using Pycharm

Tags: python, powershell, scripting, pycharm

I have been trying to figure out a way to run Powershell commands inside a Pycharm project where I can make more complicated scripts using Python. I have been searching for an answer but I have only found a few people even ask this question.
I have already verified that my Terminal inside Pycharm is set to PowerShell.

Is there a way to combine a Powershell command inside Python?
If so is there a way to do this inside Pycharm?

Comment: Every terminal is similar to your own windows Command Prompt. So you can still run Powershell commands in Windows Powershell or CMD try contacting the PYcharm developers

Comment: Look at the `subprocess` module. That is the way to get a "command prompt" inside your Python code. Start your command with `powershell` to invoke it because by default `subprocess` will give you a `cmd` prompt. (You could also change the shell in the `subprocess` call but I've never seen that done.) Changing the terminal inside PyCharm will have no effect on what the Python program does. The Python interpreter does not know it is being invoked from PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to research more about the subprocess module and I was able to find a way to do this inside a python project. Below I put a snippet of a very simple command ran with powershell that outputted what I expected so I can add to that.

```
import subprocess, sys

computer_name = "L8694C"

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["powershell.exe", "Get-ADComputer " + computer_name+ " | Select-Object Name"],
    stdout=sys.stdout)

p.communicate()
```